# root user requires sudo for some commands

Tags: debian, sudo, root

My understanding of sudo was that it ran a command as a different user.

On my fresh debian 10 box, I logged in as an account and then used su root to switch to the root account.

Now as root, some commands seem to require sudo before them. For example `reboot` gives command not found unless I use `sudo reboot`. Same for the `service` command.

Why is `sudo` required before those commands if I'm already root?

Comment: It's likely just because root's `PATH` doesn't include the directories where the commands are located, while sudo's `secure_path` does

Comment: Did you do `su` or `su -`?  The latter should result in the path being set up correctly.